# Generators of polynomial rings in relation to a quotient ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, integral-domain

I'm struggling with the following problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

> Let $R$ be a local integral domain with the unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Let $g(x), h(x)$ be monic polynomials in $R[x]$ such that $(R/\mathfrak m)[x]$ is generated (as ideal) by the reductions of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ modulo $\mathfrak m$, i.e., the polynomials obtained by reducing the coefficients of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ modulo $\mathfrak m$. Show that $R[x]$ is generated (as ideal) by $g(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Comment: Consider the subring $S=R[g,h]\subset R[x]$. Show that $R[x]$ is a finitely generated module over $S$ and use Nakayama's lemma to show it is surjective, since modulo $I$ it is, proving $S=R$.

Comment: Interesting: I've understood that $g,h$ generate $R[x]$ as the ideal generated by $g,h$  equals $R[x]$. Maybe the OP wants to clarify this.

Comment: @user26857 We want to show that if $g, h$ modulo $I$ (Understood as the coefficient of $g, h$ are reduced modulo $I$) generate $(R/I)[x]$ then $g, h$ (not reduced) generate the entire ring $R[x]$.

Comment: @Mohan I'll try this approach first thing in the morning!

Comment: @Thomas In my comment I've asked about what do you mean by "**generate**", not to repeat what you already said in the question.

Comment: @user26857 Sorry about the misunderstanding. 
An equivalent statement is $\hat{g}, \hat{h}$ (here the 'hat' means the reduction of $g, h$) are coprime and thus there exists $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\hat{g}\alpha + \hat{h}\beta = 1$ in $(R/I)[x]$ from this it follows that $\hat{g}, \hat{h}$ generate the unit ideal, i.e. they generate the entire ring $(R/I)[x]$. 
Hope this clarifies what I mean?

Comment: Ok. This is exactly what I've thought. Now please confirm if the requirement is that $g,h$ generate the unit ideal in $R[x]$.

Comment: @user26857 We want to show that $g, h$ generate the unit ideal in $R[x]$. We know that $\hat{g}, \hat{h}$ generate the unit ideal in $(R/I)[x]$.